# Separate mesh but use original index

Tags: geometry-nodes

I separated a cylinder using a vertex group and transformed the bottom part. I thought I could maybe use the original index of the vertices to transform the original mesh according to the separated part. But it seems that I have made a mistake in thinking or misunderstood how some values are handled in Geometry Nodes.

By the way I know that I could simply use the selection to transform the bottom part of the cylinder, but this setup should be part of a larger node tree, where I need to separate the mesh at some point.

[image: original cylinder]
This is the original cylinder

[image: separated and transformed bottom]
This is the separated and transformed part

[image: node tree]
And this is my none working node tree.

[image]

Comment: *"where I need to separate the mesh at some point"* ...what exactly do you mean by that? You can always separate the lower part after the transformation, can't you? I would solve it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UVjn.jpg

Comment: In my case, it's easier to separate the mesh, transform it and then apply the transformation to the original, unseparated mesh.
I animated a dog with a wagging tail. The tail will be separated, then transformed using simulation nodes and reattached. But this way I lose all my vertex groups, so I thought I should try it by applying the transformation to the original mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around a lot and trying different methods I found a solution.

[image]

The problem seems to be that the compare node only compares values with similar indices.
So I create a set of as many vertices, as I need and incorporate my transformed vertices in this set.
Then I sort this field by the original indices using [this brilliant sorting node group](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/264967/3) by Markus von Broady.

Probably there is a simpler way to achieve this, but at least it works.

[image]
Here you can find the node tree

[image]
and here is the sorting group

[image]